# JIRA screen for specific status

Tags: workflow, jira

What I am trying to achieve is, that I can use a specific screen for some status. For example just tickets in the status "New" should contain the "Original Estimate".

What I thought about was building a specific screen for these status and match status and screen. But as I see things, I just can connect screens and transitions or connect a screen to an action like creating an issue.
But both does not fit my needs, cause i want to use different screens in the same workflow for the same action and I do not want to show the screen when changing the transition. I just want to display different screens when editing issues.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of scenario I can suggest two ways to do this.

1. use javascript for a Original Estimate field..for that follow [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+display+a+Field+based+on+another+Field%27s+selection) using this you can check the status field and show or hide the field accordingly.

2.Use [Behaviours plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours) for validate the field where the status is match to your requirement.

Comment: thanks nuwan. so there is no way to do it with core JIRA funcionaltiy?

Comment: with the best of my knowledge there are no ways to do this with JIRA core functionality. above solutions I have tested recently so I can help you with those solutions if you need.:)